# Printing character position of overlapping strings stored in looped variable using grep?

Tags: bash, loops, variables, awk, grep

I have a really long string (stored in a file) filled with B's and E's and I'm trying to get position information within this file for all matches for a series of patterns that I'm looping through. I'm pretty close to getting it to work, but the problem is I'm missing instances of overlapping matches using grep.

For example, the list of patterns and string I'm searching in look like this

```
$cat CNVE_list.txt
BEEBB
BBBBEE
EEEEE
BEEEBBBBB

$cat probe_profile.txt
BBBEBEEBEEEEEEBBEEBBBB
```

And the loop I try to run looks like this

```
filename='CNVE_list.txt'
while read p; do 
    echo $p | grep -aob -f - probe_profile.txt > probe_profile_$p.txt   
done < $filename
```

The problem in this example is with line 3 in CNVE_list.txt (EEEEE). It should have two overlapping matches but only finds the first. I've read some other questions and found the issue solved with PERL with a lookbehind strategy, but not sure how to solve this with looped variables.

i.e. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276159/grep-that-works-with-overlapping-patterns

I'm dealing with a very long list of patterns and a very long string, so the more efficient the better. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How long string are we talking about?

Comment: Its ~120,000 characters, and I have to repeat with the same string in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk. I don't think it's going to be slower than `grep` but it's not lightning fast (untested with anything but provided samples, though):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
    a[$0]                                # hash search strings to a
    next
}
{
    print ++c ". string:"                # 1. is string, 2. is string reversed
    b=$0                                 # string to b
    for(i in a) {                        # loop all search words
        k=1                              # reset index 
        while(j=index(substr(b,k),i)) {  # search 
            print i,k+j-1                # output search word and index
            k=k+j                        
        }
    }
}' list profile <(rev profile)
```

Output:

```
1. string:
BEEBB 16
EEEEE 9
EEEEE 10
2. string:
BEEBB 4
BBBBEE 1
EEEEE 9
EEEEE 10
```

It relies on `rev` command to reverse the profile (and bash).

**Update**:

I tested the OP's grep solution, @stack0114106's perl solution and my awk with 120000 chars of random Bs and Es in `profile` and a 1000 items of length 10-50 in `list`:

OP (best time of three for all):

```
hits: 4506

real    0m3.977s
user    0m1.500s
sys     0m0.436s
```

GNU awk (without `rev`):

```
4511

real    0m2.576s
user    0m2.576s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Mawk (without rev):

```
4511

real    0m1.694s
user    0m1.692s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Perl:

```
4511

real    0m10.371s
user    0m10.360s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a promising solution too. While it gives me my intended output, it seems to be a lot slower than grep for my actual dataset. In addition, my example was a bit incomplete since my real script has follow-up steps inside the loop using the output of the "character position" step. To save time, follow-up steps included checking to see if the strings were palindromic before checking for the reverse pattern in the string too.

Comment: I don't know the actual data you are using to test these but see my update on execution times of proposed solutions with some random data. If these differ a lot from your tests, please describe your data more accurately.

Comment: Thanks for the side-by-side comparison. After initial testing, I realized the exceedingly longer runtimes weren't related to a code-optimization issue, but rather the much longer list of matches we were getting with our real data. The strings we were searching for contained patterns as small as 3 characters, which are repeated everywhere. That proved too time intensive for our project so we changed the scope of what we're trying to do. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl and positive lookahead,

```
perl -lne ' BEGIN { @pat=map{ chomp;$_} qx(cat CNVE_list.txt); } 
       { for my $p (@pat) { while(/(?=$p)/g) { print $p } }} ' probe_profile.txt
```

Results:

```
$ perl -lne ' BEGIN { @pat=map{ chomp;$_} qx(cat CNVE_list.txt); } 
      { for my $p (@pat) { while(/(?=$p)/g) { print $p } }} ' probe_profile.txt
BEEBB
EEEEE
EEEEE

$
```

***EDIT1:***

To get the positions of the match

```
$ perl -lne ' BEGIN { @pat=map{ chomp;$_} qx(cat CNVE_list.txt); } 
  { for my $p (@pat) { while(/(?=$p)/g) { print "$-[0], $p" } }} ' probe_profile.txt
15, BEEBB
8, EEEEE
9, EEEEE

$
```

***EDIT2:***

Check the below for optimized one.

```
$ perl -lne ' BEGIN { @pat=map{ chomp;$_} qx(cat CNVE_list.txt); 
   $p="(".join("\|",sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @pat).")" } {  
       while(/(?=$p)/g) { print "$-[0], $1" } } ' probe_profile.txt
8, EEEEE
9, EEEEE
15, BEEBB

$
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a promising solution but I apologize that I wasn't perfectly clear on my intended results. Is there an easy way to modify this code to generate the character start positions for each match as well?

Comment: yes.. it is possible using the @+, @- arrays available in Perl.. please check my EDIT1:

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll test out the new code in my pipeline. Much appreciated!

Comment: It did work, thanks, but even this solution took longer than we were hoping for. The issue sits in our intended pipeline, since identifying all possible matches in such a long string more than doubles the hits we get for short 3-character patterns. We ended up changing the scope of our pipeline, but I appreciate your help and your time. Cheers!